# Determining when no database rows match with Python mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I'm building a new Python 3 interface to an existing mySQL database. The table called "Tickets" may or may not contain a row for a particular member. I'm trying to fetch the ticket number if it exists, and do something else if it doesn't. My code looks like this:

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
  'user': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'password': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'host': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'database': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'raise_on_warnings': True
}

membernum = 9

db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
if db.is_connected():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = "SELECT ticketnum FROM Tickets WHERE membernum={} limit 1".format(membernum)
    cursor.execute(query)
    if cursor.rowcount == 0:
        print("No results")
    else:
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        ticketnum = result[0]
        print(ticketnum)
    cursor.close
    db.close
else:
    print("Connection error")
```

It works beautifully if there is a record matching that member. If not, it generates:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gary/IPPS/samplecode.py", line 22, in <module>
    ticketnum = result[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

The answer from murphy1310 took care of it! I changed the code to the following, and it worked just fine:

```
import mysql.connector

config = {
  'user': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'password': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'host': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'database': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  'raise_on_warnings': True
}

membernum = 9

db = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
if db.is_connected():
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = "SELECT ticketnum FROM Tickets WHERE membernum={} limit 1".format(membernum)
    cursor.execute(query)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result != None:
        ticketnum = result[0]
        print(ticketnum)
    else:
        print("No results")
    cursor.close
    db.close
else:
    print("Connection error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no records match the search, cursor.fetchone() throws out a None.
So, your 'result' is None.
Hence the error when you try to dig deeper into the 'result' by using result[0].
It's best you place null checks.

Comment: Looks like that was it! I changed the code to the following, and it worked just fine:

`cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchone()
if result != None:
    ticketnum = result[0]
    print(ticketnum)
else:
    print("No results")
`

Comment: I did actually upvote the answer, but I'm new and don't have 15 rep yet, so my upvote doesn't count :(

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your statement `if cursor.rowcount == 0:` is returning false (and you're falling into your else block) even when there are no tickets for the user, otherwise you wouldn't reach line 22. I would take a look at what `cursor.rowcount` is actually returning in this case.